# Is there a way to automatically change all caps text to regular text?

Tags: adobe-indesign

My document has a bunch of text that is written with caps lock on (so not with the InDesign All Caps feature). Is there a way to change 'ACCESS CONTROL FACILITY' to 'Access control facility' automatically, for example by using GREP, instead of having to retype the all caps text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GREP can't change cases. You'll need a script. Create a plain text file, name it something like *CapsToLowercase.jsx* and paste the following:

```
(function(){
  if(app.documents.length==0){return}
  var doc=app.documents[0];
  try{var range = app.selection[0].parentStory}
  catch (err){var range = doc}
  app.findGrepPreferences = null;
  app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat="\\u\\u+";
  var finds=range.findGrep();
  for (var i=0;i<finds.length;i++){
    finds[i].changecase(ChangecaseMode.lowercase);
  }
})();
```

Put it in the scripts folder and run it. (Create a safety copy of your document first, just in case. No guarantees, use at your own risk.)

Note: This will find words with two or more capital letters and change them to lowercase. In your example your result was not all lowercase. This might be more difficult to catch.

Comment: Awesome, this is a big help! Something I forgot to mention, the only words I want to change, are words that are Bold. Can you edit your script so that it only changes words with the character style 'Bold'? (The font style and character style are both named 'Bold')

Comment: Instead of app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat="\\u\\u+"; you could try something like app.findGrepPreferences.appliedCharacterStyle = "Bold"; (Not tested)

Answer (score 2):

You can select text and choose `Type > Change Case > ...` from the menu to alter the case of the selected text.

You can also set this in the `Find/Replace` dialog...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work as the text is written with caps lock on. They are all capital letters. Therefore, the option in InDesign to change case does not work. Is there still a solution, for example by using GREP to find: "(?<=\u)\u+" and then changing to Found text but lowercase?

Comment: I don't understand why "Type > Change Case" don't work. It should work. It's a command which actually changes the characters, it's not a styling option.

Comment: This all **works** as seen in the animation above. "QUID" was typed in all caps... and it works. Whether or not Caps Lock was on **makes no difference**.

Comment: The **only** reason this *may not work* is if the particular font being used has *no lowercase characters*.

Comment: @SilliusSoddus you do **not** need GREP.

Comment: There are a lot of words that I would have to change manually, that's why I'd like to use GREP or a script.

Comment: @SilliusSoddus, you can probably just select all text and do *Type > Change Case > Sentence case*. But of course not if it's in many different stories.

Comment: Unfortunately, sometimes there are acronyms that I do want to have fully capitalized :p It's a little tricky but I think a script works best.

Comment: Providing *complete* information in the question is always helpful.

Comment: @SilliusSoddus, you could use *Find/Change* to first apply an all caps *Character Style* to your list of acronyms and afterwards use *Type > Change Case > Sentence case*. Your acronyms would then be lowercase but would be styles to be uppercase. Doesn't work if you already use different character styles though.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Paragraph Style options and at the **Basic Character Formats Tab**, choose **Case** = **All Caps**, and then change it to **Normal**:

[image]

If the text is already written with the caps lock on, select the text and go to menu **Text** > **Change Case** > **Sentence Case**

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work as the text is written with caps lock on. They are all capital letters. Therefore, the option in InDesign to change case does not work. Is there still a solution, for example by using GREP to find: "(?<=\u)\u+" and then changing to Found text but lowercase?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you! I suppose there is no way to GREP this solution? But still that helps a lot.